# Trying to cache a line of code in my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, view, haml

I've tried using this code to cache the pulling of the username from flickr. However it still takes about 10 seconds to load each time i go to the page.

```
- cache do
  - flickr.photos.search(:user_id => 'userid').each do |pic| 

    - unless pic.id == 'picid'

      - photo_info = flickr.photos.getInfo(:photo_id => pic.id) 
      - photo_url = FlickRaw.url_z(photo_info)
      - thumbnail = FlickRaw.url_s(photo_info) 

      %div{"data-src" => "#{photo_url}", "data-thumb" => "#{thumbnail}"}
        .camera_caption.fadeFromBottom
          #{pic.title}
```

Comment: What cache system are you using? Memcached? I think to create a fragment cache, you need to set a uniq key for it -- I might be wrong

Comment: Are you in the development environment? Caching is not active in development...